# Можно ли делать ajax-запрос внутри ajax-запроса?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Делаю ajax-запрос внутри ajax-запроса:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '1.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '2.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Всё работает, но не уверен, правильно ли так делать?

Comment: А какой смысл от этих двух запросов? Почему нельзя в файле **1.php** выполнить какие-то действия и подключить файл **2.php**, который будет реагировать на результат работы первого файла и возвращать соответствующие данные ответом на ajax-запрос?

Comment: Я думаю, что лучше и быстрее вызвать 2.php из 1.php

Comment: бывают ситуации, когда помимо просто получения результата, надо выполнить некие действия на клиенте и сообщить серверу что они прошли успешно. Не забывайте, что и сервер может быть не один. Вопрос вполне корректен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно, это обычная асинхронная практика. Нужно ли так делать в конкретном случае, это отдельный вопрос.